# If Statement with .match(regex) in javascript not picking up spaces

Tags: javascript, regex, if-statement

Hi guys I'm trying to check if user input string contains a space. I'm using http://regexr.com/ to check if my regular expression is correct. FYI new to regex. Seems to be correct.

But it doesn't work, the value still gets returned even if there is a space. is there something wrong with my if statement or am I missing how regex works.

```
 var regex = /([ ])\w+/g;
 if (nameInput.match(regex)||realmInput.match(regex)) {
     alert('spaces not allowed');
 } else {
     //do something else 
 }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What exact input do you have for `nameInput` and `realmInput` that doesn't have the expected result?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0vx058bk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex `/([ ])\w+/g` will match any string which contain a space followed by any number of "word characters". This won't catch, for example, a space at the end of the string, not followed by anything.

Try using `/\s+/g` instead. It will match any occurrence of at least one space (including tabs).

**Update:**

If you wish to match only a single space this will do the trick: `/ /g`. There's no real need for the brackets and parenthesis, and since one space is enough even the `g` flag is kind of obsolete, it could have simply been `/ /`.

Comment: I would also offer /[ ]/g if you do not want to match other whitespace characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex doesn't match 'abc '(a word with space character at the end) . If you want to make sure, you can trim you input before check :).

You can check here https://regex101.com/

The right regex for matching only white space is

> /([ ])/g